InteractiveServer .net 8 Why I have to use "await Task.Delay(1);" to render the page loading?
This is my code from my page:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    Criterias = new ParcoursCriterias()
    {
        PageNumber = pageNumber,
        ElementsByPage = 10
    };
    ParcoursList = ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias);
}

This is the code from App.razor:
    @if(RenderModeForPage is not null)
    {
        <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@RenderModeForPage" />    
    }
    else
    {
        <HeadOutlet />
    }
</head>

<body>
    @if(RenderModeForPage is not null)
    {
        <Routes @rendermode="@RenderModeForPage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <Routes />
    }
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}

this is the service function:
public ParcoursDtoList GetAll(ParcoursCriterias criterias)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Obtenir plusieurs Parcours: #page {criterias.PageNumber} par l'utilisateur: userId"); // TODO: mettre userID

    var query = _context.Parcours
        .AsQueryable()
        .AsNoTracking();

    var comments = Filter(query, criterias);

    return comments;
}

private ParcoursDtoList Filter(IQueryable<ParcoursBd> query, ParcoursCriterias criterias)
{
    query = query
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.Creation);


    if (criterias.Name != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Name == criterias.Name);
    }
    if (criterias.Description != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => criterias.Description.Contains(p.Description));
    }

    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(query.Count() / (decimal)criterias.ElementsByPage);

    if ((criterias.PageNumber <= 0 || criterias.PageNumber > totalPages) && totalPages > 0)
        throw new PageNumberNotInRangeException(criterias.PageNumber, totalPages);

    query = Paginate(query, criterias);

    return new ParcoursDtoList()
    {
        ListParcours = _mapper.Map<List<ParcoursBd>, List<ParcoursDto>>(query.ToList()),
        PageNumber = criterias.PageNumber,
        TotalPages = totalPages,
        ElementsByPage = criterias.ElementsByPage
    };
}

private IQueryable<ParcoursBd> Paginate(IQueryable<ParcoursBd> query, ParcoursCriterias criterias)
{
    int startIndex = (criterias.PageNumber - 1) * criterias.ElementsByPage;

    return query.Skip(startIndex).Take(criterias.ElementsByPage);
}

When I use "await Task.Delay(1);", I could navigate to my page without being oblige to wait till the loading has finish for the navigation to the page take effect. So when I put the Delay on my page and I click on a button to navigate to it, it navigates to the right page and I can see the loader on it. But, like I said, when I don't put the delay and I click form another page to navigate to my page, the app waits till the loading has finished and then navigate. This is frustrating .
So my question is: am I doing the right thing to Delay on the OnInitializedAsync? What can I do so that it works properly than?
Thank you.

Yes, but why should I use ant Task to have a normal rendering...?

Revised Answer
In your original question you had:
ParcoursList = await ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias);

Which you've since changed to:
ParcoursList = ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias);

This is critical to the behaviour of OnInitializedAsync.  There's no no actual [or implied] async yielding, so you have to code in a manual yield with Task.Delay(1).  In the current format, the component lifecycle methods run to completion before yielding control to the Synchronisation Context and thus allowing the Renderer to service it's render queue [which is where StateHasChanged queues the component render].
I would recommend:

Changing your data pipeline to a DbContext Factory.  See this article for why and how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Building full async handlers for your queries and commands.


Here's a wire frame handler class for your list query [assuming you have a IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> registered] that you can fit your own code into.  I've provided it as a standalone CQS pattern List Query service.
public class ParcoursListRequestHandler
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> _factory;

    public ParcoursListRequestHandler(IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public virtual async ValueTask<returnobject> ExecuteAsync(requestobject request)
    {
        int totalRecordCount = 0;

        // Get a Unit of Work DbContext for the scope of the method
        using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        // Turn off tracking.  We're only querying, no changes
        dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

        // Get the IQueryable DbSet for TRecord
        IQueryable<Parcours> inQuery = dbContext.Set<Parcours>();

        // Apply the filter to the Query
        // Code to apply Filters

        // Get the total record count after applying the filters
        totalRecordCount =  await inQuery.CountAsync();

        // Apply the sorters to thw IQueryable instance
        // Code to apply sorters

        // Apply paging to the filtered and sorted IQueryable
        // something like
        if (request.PageSize > 0)
            inQuery = inQuery
                .Skip(request.StartIndex)
                .Take(request.PageSize);

        // Apply the mapping to the query
        // We only need to map the paged records
        var outQuery = inQuery.Select(item => mapper.MapTo(item));

        // Materialize the out list from the data source
        var list =  await outQuery.ToListAsync();

        // create the result object
        //code to build resultObject
        return resultObject;
    }
}

Original Answer
If I read this correctly, your issue is that you want to be able to click on navigation buttons on a page while the data that page displays is still loading.  The only way you can achieve that is by using await Task.Delay(1).
In your OnInitializedAsync, this line:
    ParcoursList = await ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias);

should yield [and consequently there should be no reason for the Task.Delay].
However, it's obviously not, so ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias) is a block of synchronous code wrapped in a Task which doesn't yield until it completes.
You'll need to show the content of ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias) and the type of async data pipeline it's calling for any further analysis.

"The only way" - a await Task.Yield(); should work, too, doesn't it?

@Fildor - yes it will.   @HenkHolterman will probably comment shortly extolling the virtues of Delay over Yield.  But it's doing the same thing, introducing a yield into the component lifecycle that allows it to call StateHasChanged before it awaits the task, and giving the Renderer Synchronisation Context time to service it's render queue.  If ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias) is a fully blown yielding async process, it's no needed.

Yes, I consider that a red flag should I need to use any of the two. I wasn't aware of significant benefits of Delay over Yield, .... will have a look into that. Thx for the Heads-Up.

@Fildor - the benefits are debatable: it depends what you want to achieve.  Delay uses the framework Timer to schedule the continuation, Yield returns a custom awaiter called YieldAwaiter where IsCompleted is always false, and schedules any continuations posted to Completed immediately.

Yield works, but why should I use any of them. I mean, in .net 7, that was not the case...

The net version is [almost certainly] irrelevant.  And, you're quite right in you shouldn't need to use any of them.  It's what ParcoursService.GetAll(Criterias) does and the code behind it that's critical.  Without that information, the answers end here.

post edited if you want to answer. But it is doing that whatever service function I use

I've updated my answer with recommendations to make your data pipeline code async.

The short answer:

You want a Render to happen before loading the (remaining) data.
Blazor doe not have a way to 'force' or start a Render.
But whenever the Initialization, or the handling of a UI Event releases the Thread in an await the rendering will kick in. Rendering is async with respect to the OnInitialized/OnParamsSet and OnButtonClick logic.

Since you usually don't have control over (or knowlege of) how async your GetData() code is it is better to 'release the Thread' in your UI code. It is a UI requirement anyway.
And the issue with Delay vs Yield is that Yield() doen't always work in Blazor on Wasm. await Task.Delay(1) works everywhere.
